# How do I implement Hash#all? for multidimensional hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, hash-of-hashes

Given that I have these hashes:

```
h1 = {"a" => { "b" => 1, "c" => {"d" => 2, "e" => 3} } }
h2 = {"a" => { "b" => 1, "c" => nil } }
```

And I want these results:

```
h1.multi_all?  # true
h2.multi_all?  # false
```

How would I implement the multi_all method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Hash
  def multi_all? &block
    all? do |key, value|
      if value.is_a?(Hash)
        value.multi_all?(&block)
      elsif block == nil
        value
      else
        block[key, value]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but try this: `p h2.multi_all? { |k, v| v > 0  }`. It raises undefined method exception

Comment: Does it say undefined method exception for NilClass? It's because you have a nil value in h2 which does not have a > method.

Comment: sorry, it says `undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Yeah that's because you have `"c" => nil` in your hash. If you want to use Hash#all? or this new version, all the elements within the Hash must be compatible with the block you pass in.

Comment: you're right, given `h3 = {"a" => nil }; p h3.all? { |k, v| v > 0 }`, I, of course, get the same error, so it's a consistent behaviour

Comment: Yeah it's supposed to do that. Doing `nil > 0` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Hash
  def values_r # recursive values
     self.values.map do |x|
       x.is_a?(Hash) ? x.values_r : x
     end
  end
end

h1.values_r.flatten.all?
```

PS: do you know that `all?` method also accepts a block?

Comment: Or like this?

    `class Hash
      def r_all?
         self.values.map do |x|
           x.is_a?(Hash) ? x.r_all? : x
         end.all?
      end
    end`

Comment: your variant ignores `&block`

Comment: my does not ignore: `h1.values_r.flatten.all?{ |x| x.to_i > 0 }` works